# How to use JQuery to insert a class into an unordered list item before its child sub-menu?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a multi-level mobile navigation menu with the Wordpress PHP menu function and I'm having difficulty inserting a span button (to open sub-menus) into a parent list item without it appearing after the sub-menu.

At the moment it is appearing as follows in the inspect element markup:

```
<li class=“menu-item menu-item-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-463”> ==$0
    <a href=“http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/page/“>Page</a>
    <ul class=“sub-menu”>…</ul>
    <span class=“submenu-button”>+</span>
</li>
```

I would like to be able to insert it before the ul class if possible, like this:

```
<li class=“menu-item menu-item-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-463”> ==$0
    <a href=“http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/page/“>Page</a>
    <span class=“submenu-button”>+</span>
    <ul class=“sub-menu”>…</ul>
</li>
```

The JQuery I'm currently using to add the span/button is as follows:

```
$('nav.main-menu#mobile ul li:not(.hide-mobile) ul').parent('li').append('<span class="submenu-button">+</span>');
```

I have tried using `prepend` instead of `append`, but this moved it in front of the `li a` tag as well as the `ul ul`, which is something I want to avoid.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: you need to use insertBefore http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

Comment: you can even insert before a checkbox and control the list after with css: `.submenu-checkbox + ul` and `.submenu-checkbox:checked + ul`. Another way would be to use pseudo elements and not actually insert anything... many ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jquery [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

```
$('.sub-menu').before('<span class=“submenu-button”>+</span>');
```

OR [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)

```
$( "<span class='submenu-button'>+</span>" ).insertBefore( ".sub-menu" );
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you I went for option 2, but both worked – I was on my way to figuring out that I needed to reverse the script around after reading Mohamed's answer, but I didn't know you could write it both ways. :)

Answer (score 1):

You might give this a try

```
$('.menu-item a').after('<span class="submenu-button">+</span>');
```